# How to use Netcat

Tags: scripting, netcat

I have a file on my server that has HL7 messages spread out by a space. Example below. I am wanting to send one of these messages at a time in a continual loop until stopping the script with ctrl+c. I am pretty new to `netcat` but when I try to netcat directly using `nc -l 10004` I get:

```
ncat: bind to :::10004: Address already in use. QUITTING.
```

There is a Mirth application on the appliance listening on this port already. I have no problem running the command on another appliance altogether sending it to this one if that is the only way but I need assistance sending to the IP using `netcat` and sending one message at a time with a timed gap between them.

```
MSH....
.......
.......

MSH....
.......

MSH....
.......
.......
.......
```

The file I am pulling from has multiple messages with more than one line but they are separated by a line break. (space)

Comment: You probably can batch these instead of sending one at a time if you agreed on a low level protocol to wrap the messages.

Comment: I'm wanting to send them through one at a time that way I can see how they are processing within our system. By keeping them flowing through one at a time say every 3 seconds I can make changes and see how they affect processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Mirth application already listening on port 10004 then you can't really have `netcat` also listening on that same port (the `-l` flag denotes *listen*). Perhaps you intended to write to the port rather than listen on it:

```
# Connect once and write many messages
( while :; do echo MSH....; sleep 3; done ) | nc -vvv localhost 10004
```

or

```
# Connect for each message
( while :; do echo MSH.... | nc -vvv localhost 10004; sleep 3; done )
```

Be aware that there are several different implementations of `netcat`. Every implementation seems to handle a different subset of flags...

---

Based on the new information in your question, here's another possible solution:

```
MESG=
while IFS= read -r LINE || test -n "$MESG"
do
    if test -n "$LINE"
    then
        # Build the message block
        test -z "$MESG" && MESG="$LINE" || MESG=$(printf "%s\n%s" "$MESG" "$LINE")
        continue
    fi

    # Send the message block to the service
    echo "$MESG" | nc -vvv localhost 10004
    MESG=
    sleep 3
done < /path/to/your/messagefile.txt
```

Comment: I tried while :; do echo HL7.txt | nc -vvv localhost 10004; sleep 3; done because I have the different HL7 messages in this file but it sends HL7.txt not what's inside. To verify this I sent it to another port and listened on this  port. Each HL7 message is different but is separated by a space so I am hoping to send each individually and in a loop.

Comment: @Jeff you have a file containing several lines, one line per HL7 message? Or several files each containing one message? Or something different? You didn't mention this in your Question so [please update it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/208795/edit), and then I can update my Answer to support your new information.

Comment: I updated the question thanks for any assistance!

Comment: @Jeff answer updated to incorporate the new information